# MySQL summing number of rows found across multiple tables

Tags: mysql

My tables are organized like this:

```
t_user {name, id}
t_keys {id, key}
t_thingsA {key, thing, ...}
t_thingsB {key, thing, ...}
...
```

What I'd like to do is for a specific user name, determine the sum of the number of matched rows in t_thingsA, t_thingsB, etc for any key associated with their id.

What I've got is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_user INNER JOIN t_keys ON t_user.id=t_keys.id
```

Just the number of keys. I'm unsure where to go from here - I know I probably have to append some combination of JOINs...

Comment: The ellipses are ominous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, I think you cannot do it in one query without subqueries or without join tables and doing useless work due to the computation of all the combinations of the rows of t_thingsA with all the rows of t_thingsB (for the same user).

If you only need to compute the number of rows for some specific user_name, I suggest you to do it with a UNION ALL, that is the (computationally) fastest way to do it, but surely not the more elegant one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM t_thingsA
JOIN t_keys ON t_thingsA.key = t_keys.key
JOIN t_user ON t_keys.id = t_user.id
WHERE t_user.user_name = {user_name}

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM t_thingsB
JOIN t_keys ON t_thingsB.key = t_keys.key
JOIN t_user ON t_keys.id = t_user.id
WHERE t_user.user_name = {user_name}
```

The result is that you have in the first row the number of entries in the table thingsA, in second row the number of entries in the table thingsB.

You can also do it in a more compact way, but **it isn't efficient**.. so I mention it only for completeness:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT(t_thingsA.key)) AS count_thingsA,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(t_thingsB.key)) AS count_thingsB
FROM t_user
JOIN t_keys ON t_user.id = t_keys.id
LEFT JOIN t_thingsA ON t_keys.key = t_thingsB.key
LEFT JOIN t_thingsB ON t_keys.key = t_thingsA.key
WHERE t_user.user_name = {user_name}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work as expected... just ran it against a db with 2 items in thingsA and another 2 in thingsB under 2 different keys. Got 2 instead of 4

Comment: I have misunderstood your question. In my answer I've posted the solution to count the number of rows for each table, but now I understand that you want the overall sum. In this case for the second code example you can simply do: COUNT(DISTINCT(t_thingsA.key)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(t_thingsB.key)) AS count instead of the two separate COUNT. The solution for the first code example is a little bit less trivial of this one, but it is always more efficient.